# Javascript element.display = "none" still shows div

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I'm building a website where I create elements with javascript and give content to them stored in array that I get from database, which I was able to successfully accomplish. However, I want to not display the div parent that contains all other elements added through javascript when a user clicks on a button within the div that I want not to display. However, I noticed two problems that I want to figured out why it's worked as it is. First, when I click on the button, and I apply display none to its parent, it always applies display none on the last created div instead of the corresponding div parent of the element it was clicked. Also, even though the display none is applied to the last div (though like I said, I want it to apply display none to the parent of the clicked button), the last div is still displayed on the page though it's display is none.

I need help figuring out these two problems. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks. Btw, please don't mark duplicate because I did look up for similar problems but none of the solutions apply to the problem I'm having.

Here is the javascript code:

```
var j = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {

    var mydiv = document.createElement('div');
    var element = document.createElement('p');
    var element2 = document.createElement('p');
    var raiseRating = document.createElement('button');
    var lowerRating = document.createElement('button');
    var rating = document.createElement('h1');
    var flag = document.createElement('button');

    // Index is set to hold the id so it can be used to identify the quotations whose button was clicked
    index[i] = array[i][j+3];


    //raiseRating.id = "raiseRating";
    raiseRating.innerHTML = "+";
   // lowerRating.id = "lowerRating";
    lowerRating.innerHTML = "-";
    flag.innerHTML = "flag"

    rating.innerHTML = array[i][j+2];

    element.innerHTML = '\"' + array[i][j] + '\"';
    element2.innerHTML = '\--' + array[i][j+1];
    mydiv.appendChild(element);
    mydiv.appendChild(element2);
    mydiv.appendChild(raiseRating);
    mydiv.appendChild(rating);
    mydiv.appendChild(lowerRating);
    mydiv.appendChild(flag);

   if (document.body.appendChild(mydiv)) {
       flag.addEventListener("click", function(){
           console.log("this should print");           
           mydiv.style.display = "none";
           //console.log(mydiv);
       });
   }   

}
```

UPDATE: Here is the html since someone asked for it

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
<title>Quotation Service</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cookie" 
rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Quicksand" 
rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
<div class="top-bar">
    <h1>Quotes</h1>
    <a href="register.php" >Register</a>
    <a href="login.php">Login</a>
    <a href="addQuotes.php">Add Quote</a>

</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: does console.log("this should print"); log that to the console?

Comment: Share your HTML as well in the fiddle please.

Comment: Have you tried flag.onclick = function(){yourScript}; ?

Comment: Yes, console.log prints the div and the display property of the div when printed is none. However, the div still shows up. Also, can someone tell me why the property is being applied to the last created div instead of the div parent of the element it was clicked?

Comment: Youll get marked as duplicate (or some other close reason) _not because you ask us not to_, but because you don't include any information about what you've tried, what doesn't work / does work, etc.  Show some troubleshooting effort.

Comment: It makes no sense why you or someone else down voted the question. I did research for similar questions like I explained in the description. There were just many different solutions for all similar questions I search. That's why I didn't mean to include all of them. So it makes no sense for the down vote. But anyways, it's your call. I can't change your mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not know what var array was so I just removed.This should point you in the right direction. The problem is your closures. I commented so you could notice. Read about them!

```js
var j = 0;
            for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        
                var mydiv = document.createElement('div');
                var element = document.createElement('p');
                var element2 = document.createElement('p');
                var raiseRating = document.createElement('button');
                var lowerRating = document.createElement('button');
                var rating = document.createElement('h1');
                var flag = document.createElement('button');

                // Index is set to hold the id so it can be used to identify the quotations whose button was clicked
              


                //raiseRating.id = "raiseRating";
                raiseRating.innerHTML = "+";
               // lowerRating.id = "lowerRating";
                lowerRating.innerHTML = "-";
                flag.innerHTML = "flag"

          
                mydiv.appendChild(element);
                mydiv.appendChild(element2);
                mydiv.appendChild(raiseRating);
                mydiv.appendChild(rating);
                mydiv.appendChild(lowerRating);
                mydiv.appendChild(flag);
        
                /** CLOSURE STARTS **/
                (function(flag, node){
                
                
               if (document.body.appendChild(node)) {
                   flag.addEventListener("click", function(){
                       console.log("this should print");           
                       node.style.display = "none";
                       
                   });
               }   
       }(flag, mydiv));
              /**CLOSURE ENDS **/
            }
```

Comment: He's talking about closures

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works fine. It solved both problems I posed. I will definitely read about it. I wish I had enough reps to up vote your answer. Thanks for the prompt and efficient answer

Comment: I know what you meant.  I was nudging you to edit and improve your answer to be clearer, and to potentially include a resource (or two) for "reading about closures".